# Can't find local files after pushing new git branch

Tags: django, git, github, scrapy

From the top of the directory and master branch:

1. Added a selection of the files in the directory to git : `git add file1.py file2.py file3.py file4.py file5.py
2. `git status` shows that all have been added successfully
3. git commit shows that 3 files were created which makes sense because 2 were modified and 3 were new

   ```
   > git commit -m 'viewervalidation'
   [master f73f0bc] viewervalidation

   5 files changed, 289 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
   create mode 100644 viewervalidation/file1.py
   create mode 100644 viewervalidation/file2.py
   create mode 100644 viewervalidation/file3.py
   ```
4. I push to master and am rejected because of work I don't have locally

   ```
   > git push origin master
   To github.com:groupflix/data-science.git
    ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxx.git'
   hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
   hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
   hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
   hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
   ```
5. So I decide to create a new branch called vv_exp1 and push to that:

   ```
   > git checkout -b 'vv_exp1'

   M   general_scripts/data_munging/neo4j_query.py
   D   general_scripts/data_munging/remove_bad_users.py
   M   nlp_api/summarizer/classes/review.py
   M   nlp_api/summarizer/modeling/pull_openend_sentiment_dataset.py
   Switched to a new branch 'vv_exp1'

   > git push origin 'vv_exp1'

   Counting objects: 749, done.
   Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (722/722), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (749/749), 833.12 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
   Total 749 (delta 374), reused 3 (delta 0)
   remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (374/374), done.
   To github.com:groupflix/data-science.git
    * [new branch]      vv_exp1 -> vv_exp1
   ```
6. This is where things get really weird. I go to run scrapy (which I'm using in this directory) and the command I've used for weeks with success `scrapy crawl NameSearch -a filename=12.csv` yields the following:

   ```
   Scrapy 1.0.3 - no active project

   Unknown command: crawl

   Use "scrapy" to see available commands
   ```

On top of that, I go to look in the directory and find that all the new files that were 'created' are now gone. When I switch to master they are still gone and scrapy still doesn't work. If I go on github, they are there on the branch I pushed to, but if I try to pull it says I'm up to date even though I'm missing those files. Any idea what happened to my files and why Scrapy is broken just from creating a new branch and pushing?

Answer (score 1):

## 4 is telling you that your local branch is not up to date with remote.

Can you try:

```
git branch -a

git remote show origin
```

The first command will list all branches. The second command gets you the remote branch. Try:
    git pull
before you push up to origin.

Comment: thanks for the response! I figured out the problem - viewervalidation wasn't in my sparse-checkout file (which I had forgotten I had been using)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was, I'm using sparse-checkout to only pull some of the repo, but my sparse-checkout file hadn't yet included the viewervalidation directory I'm trying to pull here. When I added the file path it solved the problem.